# Query to datetime field with date condition only in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp query conditions, where i have only date which have to meet the conditions with datetime field of table. suppose i have date only(2013-09-21) and field is (2013-09-21 07:45:23). i have get problem to give the condition here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If @Aryan 's solution doesn't work because you need to convert between formats at the database, then you want to use the MySQL function `DATE`.  This would change the find example to be this:

```
$row = $this->Model->find('all',
                    array('fields' => array('........'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'DATE(Story.created) >' => $date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date_string = "2013-09-21";
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_string));
$row = $this->Model->find('all',
                    array('fields' => array('........'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Story.created >' => $new_date)));
```